# How to add to a List from IO in Haskell.

Tags: list, haskell, io

I am trying to write a simple function which reads in one line at a time (which I know will be integers) and then stores them in to a list. For the life of me however, it seems like the list comes out to empty.

```
import System.IO
import Control.Monad

type Int2 = [Int]

valueTab = [] :: [Int]

app [ ] list = list 
app (h:t) list = h:(app t list)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering -- DO NOT REMOVE

    -- Auto-generated code below aims at helping you parse
    -- the standard input according to the problem statement.

    input_line <- getLine
    let n = read input_line :: Int
    let value = [] :: [Int]

    replicateM n $ do
        input_line <- getLine
        let pi = read input_line :: Int
        hPutStrLn stderr (show input_line)
        hPutStrLn stderr (show valueTab)
        return $ app valueTab [pi]


    -- hPutStrLn stderr "Debug messages..."

    -- Write answer to stdout


    --putStrLn input_line
    return ()
```

So when I run this with 
8
6
4
3 all on their own lines, 
It prints 6, [], 4, [], 3 [].

Is this a problem with my printing, with my list declaration, with the way that I store them or? I have both value and valueTab to check whether it was a scope problem.

Note: The code is boilerplate code on a coding website that tests it on it's platform. Assume replicateM is just a loop that runs through the code x number of times.

Comment: Variables on Haskell are immutable. You are evaluating `app valueTab [pi]` (which could have been written `valueTab ++ [pi]` by the way) but this doesn't change the value of `valueTab`. It cannot. `valueTab` is forever an empty list.

Comment: OTOH the result of `replicateM` function (it's a function that returns a value) could be interesting but you never do anything with it. Perhaps try to explore this possibility.

Comment: If you’re allowed to throw out the boilerplate, you might find this a lot simpler to write using `interact`, `words`, `map` and `read`.

Comment: Thanks for the insights in to haskell. I see I am thinking too much Java on this problem haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're doing a problem on codinggame.com.  Other coding sites seem to do a better job with their Haskell templates, particularly for beginner exercises -- the template usually takes care of *all* the input and output, and you just need to supply the missing pure function.  In contrast, codinggame.com's Haskell templates seem to assume the beginner has a pretty firm grasp of the IO monad, and leave out a lot of essential details (e.g., the fact that the result of the `replicateM` action should actually be bound to a variable) which you're expected to fill in.

The `replicateM` call in the original template probably looked something like:

```
replicateM n $ do
    input_line <- getLine
    let pi = read input_line :: Int    -- maybe this line was there, maybe not
    return ()
```

This expression creates a composite IO action that, when executed, will repeat the following subaction `n` times:

- read a line, binding the string read to `input_line`
- prepare to convert that line to an integer value `pi` (though this is never done because `pi` isn't used)
- regardless of the string read, return "unit" (the value `()`) as the result of the subaction

The value of the composite action is then a list of the values returned by the subactions.  Since those were all units, the final value of the composite action is a list `[(),(),()...()]`, with one `()` for each line read.  However, because the value of this composite action is never bound to a variable (i.e., because there's no `result <- ...` before the `replicateM` expression), this list is thrown away.

So, this template provides a needlessly verbose method of reading `n` lines of input and doing nothing with them.

Fortunately, all you need to do to make this template do something useful is to have the subaction return a value that's useful (e.g., the integer `pi`) which will cause the composite action to return a list of the integers read, and then make sure you bind the resulting list to a variable using the `<-` notation.

In other words, you want to write:

```
main = do
    ...

    pis <- replicateM n $ do
        input_line <- getLine
        let pi = read input_line :: Int
        return pi

    hPutStrLn stderr (show pis)
```

You won't need the helper function `app`, and you won't need to pre-declare a list `valueTab` to contain the result.  The result is automatically produced by `replicateM`, and you just need to name it so you can use it.

The complete working program will look like:

```
import System.IO
import Control.Monad

type Int2 = [Int]

main :: IO ()
main = do
    hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering -- DO NOT REMOVE

    -- Auto-generated code below aims at helping you parse
    -- the standard input according to the problem statement.

    input_line <- getLine
    let n = read input_line :: Int
    let value = [] :: [Int]

    pis <- replicateM n $ do
        input_line <- getLine
        let pi = read input_line :: Int
        return pi

    hPutStrLn stderr (show pis)

    -- hPutStrLn stderr "Debug messages..."
    -- Write answer to stdout

    return ()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that explanation. I can't believe it was that simple, and at the same time, I would never have been able to figure that out just by looking at it. But from your explanation, I definitely have a little bit stronger of a grasp of the concepts here. Now I can actually get in to trying to solve the puzzle! Thanks again for taking the time to answer. Also, nice work nailing it on the head that it was from codingame!